# How to list keyboard shortcuts defined by a webpage?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, website

My question initially arise from using Linked In (using Firefox), where reaching the search bar requires me to use the mouse pointer, when in other sites I am aware of a keyboard shortcut. For example on Duckduckgo, `h` will lead me there, and on [Vortaro.net](https://vortaro.net) it's `Esc`. On Mediawiki websites I extensively use `alt+shift+f`.

I didn't found a documentation for Linked In, which might provide me a solution for this specific case.

But more generally, is there a trivial way to discover which elements have a provider defined shortcut? That is in contrast to solutions which are client defined, like [Tridactyl](https://github.com/tridactyl/tridactyl).

Comment: In most browsers, if you want to place the focus on the address bar, you just have to press F6, but I'm not sure if that's what you want.

Comment: Hi @Didier. No it's not what I'm looking for. Thanks for the type anyway.